# [Android Studio]Volley GET method return 400 error. POSTMAN can work

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to send a jsonrequest to my project server with a param and want to get an jsonObject as a response. Below is my code.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Const.URL_SERVER_STOCK, null
            , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println("Response is: "+response.toString());
            test.setText(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error: " + error
                    + "\nStatus Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode
                    + "\nResponse Data " + error.networkResponse.data.toString()
                    + "\nCause " + error.getCause()
                    + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> header = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            header.put("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            return super.getHeaders();
        }
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("stockId", String.valueOf(id));
            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Below is what I got:

```
I/System.out: id passing: 2
E/Volley: [3415] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://cs309-jr-4.misc.iastate.edu:8080/stock
D/str_log_req: Error: com.android.volley.ClientError
    Status Code 400
    Response Data [B@e14f879
    Cause null
    messagenull
```

Below is my POSTMAN RESULT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC3Bh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLCPR.png)

Comment: Is the url in the android have parameter? `Unexpected response code 400 for http://cs309-jr-4.misc.iastate.edu:8080/stock` the log doesn't have stockId

Comment: no, the parameter will be passed by getParams()

Comment: I think volley getParam is use for POST method not GET method
Check this tutorial: `https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put`

Comment: Yes! you remind me that, I can just simply modify my URL address. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok I will post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a GET, you should include the parameters in you url

```
Const.URL_SERVER_STOCK + "?stockId=" + selectedId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Volley getParam() can be use for the POST method not GET method. Follow the tutorial below for the details: `https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put`